# move to the new version from 3.5

Tags: netty

i'm evaluation the new Netty 4.0 and try to understand what i will need to do to move to the new version from 3.5.
I have couple for querstion about potring to Netty 4.0.0

1. In Netty  4.0.0 the messageReceived method replace with inboundBufferUpdated method. 
   A user enqueues one or more messages to an inbound (or outbound) buffer and triggers an inboundBufferUpdated (or flush) event.
   This approach implies the synchronization of an inbound (or outbound) buffer in case the execution of Handlers are in the user threads. 
   Can you suggest another way to send a inbount (or outbound) message without the synchronization object, for example as in Netty 3.5 by messageReceived method.
2. In the Netty 3.5 we use the SimpleChannelHandler, which provides method for both event type. How do I use the same approach in the Netty 4.0.0?

Answer (score 1):

Read [this](http://netty.io/wiki/new-and-noteworthy-in-4.x.html)... It should answer all your questions and also give more ideas about the changes..

Comment: Thank you for answers.

I have a lot of time working with this document and saw the examples, but still no clarity on these issues.

If I have multiple Handlers which were added to the Pipeline, after the fireInboundBufferUpdated event occurs
 the inboundBufferUpdated method of the the first Handler will be called.

Comment: public void inboundBufferUpdated(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) {   
 if (ctx.hasInboundByteBuffer()) {   
     ByteBuf in_buf = ctx.inboundByteBuffer(); 
     Queue<MyMsg> out = ctx.nextinboundMessageBuffer(); 
       ...
      out.add(new MyMsg(in_buf));
      
  }else{
 Queue<MyMsg> in = ctx.inboundMessageBuffer(); 
        Queue<MyMsg> out = ctx.nextinboundMessageBuffer(); 
        for (;;) {   
         MyMyMsg msg = in.poll(); 
           if (buf == null)          
               break;
            ...  
            out.add(msg);
           
        }
  }
  ctx.fireInboundBufferUpdated ();
}

Comment: All operation with queue ( poll, add ) are synchronized and can be affected on  system's performance.
Can you suggest another way pass message to the next handler by fire InboundBufferUpdated event?